# Displaying a class name

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys i have a Javascript code here which creates HTML buttons onload with the buttons attributes being fetched from the database through an ASP page. Now i want to display these attributes, i can display the id, type and value but the class shows as undefined. i went to the page on the browser and inspected the element and the class is shown, but not on the alert  box. Please help...

```
function createButtons(tbID, tbClass, tbType, tbValue, onClick) {
return '\n<input'
                + (tbID ? ' id=\'' + tbID + '\'' : '')
                + (tbClass ? ' class=\'' + tbClass + '\'' : '')
                + (tbType ? ' type=\'' + tbType + '\'' : '')
                + (tbValue ? ' value=\'' + tbValue + '\'' : '')
                            + (onClick ? ' onclick=\''+ onClick + '\'':'')
                            + '>';

}


function DisplayButtons(cableData) {

var newContent = '';

$.each(cableData, function (i, item) {

newContent += createButtons(
        item.CommonCable,
        "unclickedButton",
        "submit",
        item.CommonCable,
        'alert(this.id + " " + this.class + " "+"clicked")'
    );

});


$('#Categories').html(newContent);  

}
```

Comment: Yuck. You can use jQuery, so why fill in the `onclick` attribute with a string?

Comment: Yuck. You can use jQuery, so why build the element by string interpolation at all? It's not even _shorter_.

Comment: I suggest you learn about `console.log()`. Using `alert()` to debug is both annoying and unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

change `this.class` to `this.className`..

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the alert parameter, pass in this:

```
'alert(this.id + " " +' +  $(this).attr(class) + ' + " "+"clicked")'
```

You can use jQuery to get the class name.

Comment: @Alvaro G. Vicario thanks i know about console.log and i have used it and the same thing happens, it says undefined